# Vuejs Render subcomponent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to render one component inside another. But then running the subcomponent is not applying.

Everything is global:

**Index**

```
<script src=" <?= Helpers::asset('assets/js/vue/componenteA.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src=" <?= Helpers::asset('assets/js/vue/componenteB.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

**App.js**

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app-welcome',
  components: {
    'componenteA': componenteA,
    'componenteb' : componenteb
  }...
```

**componenteA**

```
const componenteA = {
  template: "<div><p>xxx</p> 
                        <div  v-for="d in DEMO">
                          <componenteB :x="d"></componenteB>
                        </div>   ......</div>",
  props: {
    x: { type: Object }
  } 
data(){}
```

When I run the code, everything inside componentA is rendered to the screen,
however, the content of componentB is not displayed.

If I order componentB to be displayed outside of componentA, it is shown successfully.

My question is how to make componentB rendering happen inside componentA.

Informs that the server does not have NODE, NPM, VUECLI.

thanks.

Comment: Probably a typo error in `'componenteb' : componenteb`, there should be big `B`s. Also you have to `import componenteB from './componenteB';` inside your componenteA in order to use it

Comment: what about using this statement for loading component: `Vue.component(name, def)`

Comment: @MohammadMirsafaei This statement does not load the component - it simply registers it inside Vue so you can then reference it inside templates. The loading of the component happens through the `import` statement.